# Laravel 9 API auth works with Passport, but when I try to access Auth::User() in web.php routed function, it doesnt work

Tags: php, laravel

Inside my routes/api.php file, I have something like this:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
})->name('api.user');
```

Which works, I am even able to access Auth::user() when I use the following inside routes/api.php:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {

    // our routes to be protected will go in here
    Route::post('/example', [ExampleController::class, 'example'])->name('example.api');

});
```

This takes us to the example function inside the Example Controller, where I am able to access:

```
Auth::user()->id;
```

So far, so good. However, when I try to use Passport auth inside routes/web.php like this:

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
        Route::name('google.index')->get('google', [ExampleTwoController::class, 'index']);

 });
```

I am unable to access the following inside ExampleTwoController's index function:

```
 Auth::user()
```

It all appears as null. Auth::user() appears as null.

Why isn't the web.php route passing the Auth user info? I am even logged in when I try to load these pages, the browser has a cookie with my auth token, but it keeps redirecting me to the login page even when the cookie is there with the auth token.

I have even updated the web driver to Passport inside config/auth.php

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport', //update this line
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
auth()->user()
```

global function.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::name('google.index')->get('google',function (Request $request)=> {

        dd( auth()->user(),  Auth::user(), $request->user,  $request->token );

    });
});
```

Your api routes know who user is *(most likely)* because you are providing token in request header. Then Passport determines who is that user based on token.

Comment: Are there two code blocks? Or is auth()->user() connected to global function somehow?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Is the first code block `auth()->user()` separate? Or should **global function.** be in the code block below?

Comment: Separate from what? Below what?

Comment: I guess I don't understand what your answer says.

Comment: `auth()->user()`  is a global function which returns user object.
`dd()` is a global function which stops script execution and displays value provided inside brackets (or list of values)

So if you combine these two, you get output which prints user object. But since it stops script execution, you need to first try outputing one `dd()` then delete it, try another etc. Maybe that pard is confusing. So in summray, try this: `dd( auth()->user(),  Auth::user(), $request->user,  $request->token);` To print all of these values in one script call

Comment: That's great. Could you update your answer with that. I'll upvote.